# Apache, root, subdomain and subdirectory

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I jave a server with multiple directories on root :

- /site
- /forum
- /wiki
- and so on...

When I visit the site, the URL is mysite.org/site or mysite.org/forum.

What I would like is too configure my .htaccess to behave like this :

- the site directory is used as root directory : the URL is mysite.org/blabla, but it shows the content of mysite.org/site/blabla
- the others directory are used as subdomains : the URL is forum.mysite.org but it shows mysite.org/forum

I can't manage to have this working...

Currently my .htaccess is like this :

```
RewriteEngine On

# Map http://www.example.com to /site.
RewriteRule ^$ /site/ [L]

# Map http://www.example.com/x to /site/x unless there is a x in the web root.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/site/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /site/$1

# Add trailing slash to directories without them so DirectoryIndex works.
# This does not expose the internal URL.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1/

# Disable auto-adding slashes to directories without them, since this happens
# after mod_rewrite and exposes the rewritten internal URL, e.g. turning
# http://www.example.com/about into http://www.example.com/site/about
DirectorySlash off
```

Could someone help me please ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is possible with .htaccess. Anyway I think the best/right way to do it is by splitting the subdirectories into different web sites served by the same apache.

Eg:

move `/var/www/mysite.org/wiki/*`  to -> `/var/www/wiki.mysite.org/*`
move `/var/www/mysite.org/forum/*`  to -> `/var/www/forum.mysite.org/*`
keep `/var/www/mysite.org there`

then build apache configurations like:

**mysite.conf:**

```
# domain: mysite.org
# public: /var/www/mysite.org

<VirtualHost *:80>
  # Admin email, Server Name (domain name), and any aliases
  ServerAdmin admin@mysite.org
  ServerName  mysite.org
  ServerAlias www.mysite.org *.mysite.org mysite.org

  # Index file and Document Root (where the public files are located)
  DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
  DocumentRoot /var/www/mysite.org/

  <Directory /var/www/mysite.org>
    Options -Indexes
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    Options -Includes
    Options -ExecCGI
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
  </Directory>

  # Log file locations
  LogLevel warn
  ErrorLog  /var/log/apache2/mysite.org_error.log
  CustomLog /var/log/apache2/mysite.org_access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

**wiki.conf:**

```
# domain: wiki.mysite.org
# public: /var/www/wiki.mysite.org

<VirtualHost *:80>
  # Admin email, Server Name (domain name), and any aliases
  ServerAdmin admin@mysite.org
  ServerName  wiki.mysite.org
  ServerAlias wiki.mysite.org

  # Index file and Document Root (where the public files are located)
  DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
  DocumentRoot /var/www/wiki.mysite.org/

  <Directory /var/www/wiki.mysite.org>
    Options -Indexes
    Options -FollowSymLinks
    Options -Includes
    Options -ExecCGI
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
  </Directory>

  # Log file locations
  LogLevel warn
  ErrorLog  /var/log/apache2/wiki.mysite.org_error.log
  CustomLog /var/log/apache2/wiki.mysite.org_access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

This way you can specify different settings (log files, config includes, etc.) on per-site basis, and do cool stuff like using mpm_itk to run each site with different UID/GID.

Comment: Unfortunatly, I am not on a dedicated server, so I can't change the conf files. This is why I wanted to do it by editing htaccess.